# single pool skimmer or multiple better

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Im designing a swimming pool, long rectangular shape with skimmers. Im having some debate as to whether one single skimmer at the centre of the long side, or multiple skimmers positioned along the long side is best. The question being, is the gain in proximity to each zone of the pool water achieved by multiple skimmers more than offset by the loss in suction at each skimmer? This problem assumes that all skimmers are connected to a single pump. If each skimmer had its own pump then clearly the more skimmers the better. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Re, "If each skimmer had its own pump then clearly the more skimmers the better." I'm not so sure about that. The issue here is that the system is going to cause water to circulate--flowing through the skimmers--and you want to know whether the overall circulation will have any "dead zones" where objects floating on the surface tend to congregate without flowing toward any particular skimmer. I suspect that a demented pool designer, armed with a deep knowledge of fluid dynamics, could create a pool that had a significant dead zone in spite of having many skimmers.

Comment: True dead zones are an issue - if you had 10 discharge jets and 10 skimmers directly opposite then surely that would provide an optimal situation Vs 10 discharge jets and one skimmer in the middle on the opposite side?

Comment: Thought experiment pool contains just 2 molecules of water and two nano skimmers each the width of 1 water molecule 
a- 2- molecules of water trying to pass through 1 pipe or
b-  2 pipes 1 molecule each

Pipes are the width of 1 molecule and the water molecules have zero distance to travel.

Comment: By increasing from 1  > 2 pipes you have increased surface area, therefore you have reduced pressure as a function of area which is not linear but squared.
 
However friction is also a function of area and by using two pipes rather than 1 you have reduced friction as a function proportional to the square of the area 

Therefore providing the molecules have zero distance to travel both  scenarios are equal. Pressure loss is mitigated by friction loss as bot are proportional to area of pipe.

Comment: However if the molecules need to travel a real distance then the neutrality between the two scenarios no longer exists.
As the length of the pipes increase above zero the friction forces are a multiple of area * length . however the pressure loss at each point of contact remains purely a function of area. Therefore as the pipe length extends towards infinity the frictional losses from a single pipe become more significant than the pressure gain in a linear fashion.